# Angular2 post form

Tags: angular, angular-routing

i am new on using angular2 framework. i have a form that if submitted it transfer the data to the API. the transfer function work properly. but then the form. after i click submit there is nothing change on the form. the data that i inputted is still there. i want if i submitted the form it can redirect to another component instead.

here is my code component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


import {CustomerService} from '../services/customer.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-register',
  templateUrl: './app-register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-register.component.css'],
  providers:[CustomerService]
})
export class AppRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  register: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  error = '';

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder, 
    private service: CustomerService,
    private router: Router
    ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.register = this.fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      government: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      address: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
      phone: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
    });
  }

    onSubmit() {
    this.service.registerCustomer(this.register.value).subscribe(
      result => {
          if (result === true) {
              this.router.navigate(['/']);
          } else {
              this.error = 'data is incorrect';
              this.loading = false;
          }
      }, 
      error => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.error = error;
      });
  }

}
```

here is my service if u needed

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import {RegisterData} from '../model/model-register';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerCustomer( registerdata:RegisterData) : Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/customer/new", JSON.stringify(registerdata), {headers: this.headers})
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }


  }
```

Thanks for helping guys :)

Comment: Have u tested a console.log(); when the result === true to see if the service is working?

Comment: Also `result === true` is redundant. `if (result)` is sufficient.

Comment: I did not get it , can u explain more ? :)

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid I'm just saying this statement (`if (result === true)`) in OP is *redundant*.. and can be simplified to `if (result) { ... } `.

Comment: What i want to understand is : is the service working and the redirection that is not working ?  Or the submit is not working ? Where is the problem exactly?..

Comment: @Med_Ali_Rachid the problem is: i write any text on the text field on my form. and then i click submit button. but the text that i wrote before on the text field is still there. the normal form i believe when i submit the form the text field will be empty again. thats the problem

Comment: so you say i have to delete that? @developer033

Comment: @dedypuji, if you want to reset the form, just use `this.register.reset()`, but I don't understand, if you are navigating away from component, why need to reset? I'm also a bit confused of what exactly is the problem here. The form, or the navigation?

Comment: @AJT_82 nice its worked man. the reset stuff

Comment: @dedypuji Okay, great, glad to hear! :)